# How to make MongoDB digest a javascript file AFTER basic initialisation of the database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker, mongodb-query, admin

I have a MongoDB container running since some time, and now I need to insert some data to the database, without losing all the data (I could do docker system prune --volumes, but this will erase all data).

I have written a script that would do all this:

```
db.auth('root', 'example');

    db.createUser(
    {   user: "admin",
        pwd: "admin",
        roles:[{role: "root" , db:"admin"}]})

    db = db.getSiblingDB('dev');

    db.approver.insert({"email":"some@email.com","approverType":"APPROVER"});
    db.approver.insert({"email":"someother@email.com","approverType":"ACCOUNTANCY"});
    db.approver.insert({"email":"another@email.com","approverType":"ACCOUNTANCY"});
```

I have expanded my docker-compose to copy my `config.js` file to `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

Recreating the container is doing nothing like the script is not running.

I have found out that MongoDB is running scripts in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` only once.

When I am trying to run the script in the container using `mongo` cli, I get:

```
root@038a4fb0736e:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d# mongo config.js 
MongoDB shell version v4.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("c21d3faa-93a3-4da1-9a8c-b3ebce178929") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.5
Error: Authentication failed.
2019-06-07T09:31:31.872+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't add user: command createUser requires authentication :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1491:15
@config.js:3:1
failed to load: config.js
```

Is there a way to run this script properly? Or a method to authorize me to create the admin user?

The docker-compose fragment:

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dev
    volumes:
      - ./config.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/config.js
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      mongonetwork:
volumes:
    mongodbdata:
networks:
    mongonetwork:
      external: true
```

Comment: Why not insert the data and create image of that container, and then use the new image to create containers?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your DB was initially created with different values for `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and/or `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

These variables are only used to initialize the root user on a brand new DB. As long as your DB exist, they are not used anymore. As you already found out, this is the same for scripts in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.

This is probably why your `db.auth('root','example');` call is failing.

If you can't remember the credentials, you can [reset the root password](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/mongodb/administration/change-reset-password/).